# Adding Subview to UINavigationController Subclass

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have subclass the UINavigationController and add a custom subview underneath the UINavigationBar. I update the position of my subview in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method. However, with this method when I add a viewController to the navigationController, the viewController's view will be hidden behind my custom subview. **How should I add the subview so does it does not cover up my viewController's view?**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.addSubview(tabView)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    tabView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + self.navigationBar.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40.0)
    navigationViewHeight = tabView.frame.origin.y + tabView.frame.size.height

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't embed your navigation controller in a UITabBarController?  Going this route will ensure that you get all this functionality 'for free'.

Comment: @WayneHartman because I want to have the tab bar on top of the screen and customize its look and feel. Haven really looked into that possibility but my experience with using UITabBarController is that it is quite painful to customize.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider subclassing UINavigationBar instead of UINavigationController. Here's an example of adding a subview to a custom nav bar https://gist.github.com/timothyarmes/7080170